# sql query to take data out of multiple tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have (several tables say) 4 tables, A, B, C and D and they are linked by some common values like:

```
TableA(A1,A2,A3,A4) ---> TableB(A1,B2,B3,B4) ---> TableC(C1,C2,B3,C4) ---> TableD(D1,D2,D3,C4)
                               |                             |
                         TableX(X1,B2,X3,X4)      TableY(Y1,Y2,Y3,C4)
```

For each unique value of `A2`, there is a value `A1`. Same Value `A1` is there in `TableB`.
Similarly in `TableB`, for each value of `A1`, there are some particular values `B2,B3,B4`,
In the same way in `TableC` and `TableD` also, for each value of `B3` and `C4` respectively there are particular remaining values.

In addition to the linear flow there are multiple flows inbetween (like from TableB to TableX or TableC to TableY)

I want to extract some columns say for instance `A1,A2,B2,C1,D1` and `C4` if I am given a value of `A2`.

I am new to this type of queries and short of time to complete the task.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: I guess a simple `JOIN` would solve this problem

Comment: possible duplicate of [Difference between INNER and OUTER joins](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38549/difference-between-inner-and-outer-joins)

Answer (score 0):

You must use a multiple join like this:

```
Select TableA.A1,TableA.A2,TableB.B2,TableC.C1,TableC.C4 from
TableA join TableB on TableA.A1=TableB.A1
join TableC on TableB.B3=TableC.B3    
where A2='....'
```

Answer (score 0):

Although a horrible question posted with poor sample of tables and explanations, Start first with a query on how to tie all the fields together.  Once you have all your JOIN conditions established, THEN add the WHERE you are looking for specific elements from the data

```
select *
   from
      TableA a
         JOIN TableB b
            on a.A1 = b.A1
            JOIN TableC c
               on b.b3 = c.b3
               JOIN TableD d
                  on c.c4 = d.c4
   where
          a.field = '?'
      AND d.field = '?'
```

or whatever criteria you are looking for...  and just use the alias references, such as (a, b, c, d)

Notice from the layout I have my SQL, you can exactly see the hierarchy of how one table connects to the other by simple visual indentation and very clear column relations between the respective tables.

Comment: thanks for bearing with such a horrible question, but working for the first time and need to finish the project today, i had no other option. I got the flow but what if Flow is not a linear. Like from TableA to TableB to TableC to TableD is existing (as in initial question) but if I have one sub-flow say from TableB to TableX and may be another subflow like Table C to TableY. How should I accomodate this? Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Jivi, you must have SOME sort of connection between the tables of common elements.  That is the whole point of a relational database.  Just add join's to the respective other tables.  If tableC can join to D, X and Z, just have each respectively joined to the C table.  if there is not a guaranteed record in say.. tableX, then do it as a LEFT JOIN meaning I want the record from the left table (ex: TableC) even if there is not one in the right side table (tableX).  If you have more of these subflows, update your question and I'll revise my answer.